# C# lock blocking or sleeping longtime between locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, locking, mutex

I have a program that has parallel threading timers. Basically these timers are set to run a method every 10 seconds. In that method the thread gains a lock on a list to make a copy to do it's work.

```
private object access = new object();
PeriodTask(){
    lock(access){
        copy = list.Where(e => e.valid).toList();
    }
    foreach (var element in copy)
        do some not so quick work.
}
```

I also have a way to get information on those elements that also asks for a lock. And gets a copy

```
informationMethod(){
    lock(access){
        return list.Select(element => new serializableElement(element)).toList()

    }
}
```

The reason I need locks is because there are methods to add and remove items from this list that lock it as well. But I'm not even calling them yet.

The problem I'm having is that the information retrieving method blocks or sleeps for a long time in between instances of this class. There can be around 10 of these and it seems to get access to 2 or 3 at a time but the process can take a minute and a half to two minutes to get all of them. The first method I mentioned that is executed on a timer gets access just fine when it should and releases the lock instantly but the other struggles to execute even though it's the main thread of execution.

I have a couple tests that instantiates a manager of these classes.

```
//sets up updaters test
var manager = new manager(config);
Assert.IsNotNull(manager);
Assert.IsFalse(manager.UpdatersRunning);
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, manager.Updaters.Count());//calls the informationMethod on each updater
manager.Dispose();
//This test doesn't even run the period task


//Waits to start updaters test
var manager = new StatusObjectManager(config);
Assert.IsNotNull(manager);
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, manager.Updaters.Count());
Assert.IsFalse(manager.UpdatersRunning);
Assert.AreEqual(0, manager.Updaters.Count(u => u.Running));
manager.StartUpdaters();
Assert.IsTrue(manager.UpdatersRunning);
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, manager.Updaters.Count(u => u.Running));
manager.Dispose();
//This test runs the period tasks and checks to make sure their running. Or at least 1.
//THis test takes a long time for the first informationMethod bout but not the other 2.

The code in the manager looks like this
return updaters.select(u => new serialUpdater(su));
```

It doesn't need a lock at this point because that list isn't modified.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be going on. I'm not sure how to tell if the thread is blocking on the lock or just sleeping for an abnormal amount of time.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework you use?

Comment: .NET 4.0, Thinking I should use the Concurrent Collections? I've considered it but heard that the concurrentbag which would be best for my solution had some issues with performance as well. But I may just have to go there if I can't get this going.

Comment: Yes, i think in ConcurrentBag<T>

Comment: Why not a ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Comment: I hadn't considered the dictionary because it didn't seem necessary to have access to any one element of the list, at least not on a frequent basis. And order wasn't an issue. It also uses more memory, right? But you're right if it doesn't have the performance problem like the bag I can try it.

Comment: What type of timer you use? System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: Yes. The tasks are fairly short but need to be run everyso often in a long running service. I was using tasks with sleep timers but they were impossible to cancel with the thread sleeping and I didn't care to learn how to control a blocking mechanism for those threads when this was easier.

Comment: Concurrentdictionary is performing better than mine but it is still taking a long time. Tests were taking around 1:45 minutes, now 50 seconds. Keeping in mind that the manager alone takes about 15 seconds to build and instanciate. So much better but still not fast.

Comment: Scratch that thing about the manager taking 15 seconds. It takes 4 seconds to make which makes sense because it makes a few db calls and reflection set up. The other 12 seconds was from a call to Updaters methods that just retrieves the Ienumerable of updaters it's tracking. It doesn't do any counts or anything, just checked for notnull and it still takes 12 seconds. Adding the count makes it take 48 seconds which is consistent with the other tests.

Comment: Found the problem. Some of the elements use reflection to do some work and one of them takes a long time to retrieve it's value. Added a cached property to that Everything executes in a snap. I', not sure what to mark as the answer because it was unrelated to blocking. Since the concurrent dictionary did help some do I mark that?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) rather than the `lock` in such a situation. That way, any number of readers can be accessing the list concurrently. The only time they'd block is if something grabbed the write lock.

Comment: Justin. I used the Concurent dictionary. I may as well mark it as the answer since that is what I used to prevent races. Mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0):

The first step here is to add logging. Simple `Trace.WriteLine` before and inside the lock, you can also get/set the `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` on creating, reading a `Thread` so you can tell which `Thread` is in the method.

The next step would be to implement something not as clean, but faster, ala, [System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) . The nice thing about this is, it'll allow all threads to read at the same time, but block everything on a write. So essentially you're only blocking on a write.

Also, be aware of reference types when doing a `ToList` or `ToArray` etc.

```
void Main()
{
    var slist = new List<Chunk>();
    var chunk = new Chunk{Name="asdf"};
    slist.Add(chunk);
    var slist2 = slist.ToList();
    slist[0].Name = "asdf2";
    Console.WriteLine(slist[0].Name); // outputs: asdf2
    Console.WriteLine(slist2[0].Name); // outputs: asdf2
}

public class Chunk
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```